# Twitter Log In - Thread 1 Sigabrt Error in App Delegate and App Crashes

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, twitter, parse-platform

I am trying to create a simple parse log in that integrates both `Twitter` and `Facebook` as log in options in `iOS9`. `Facebook` login works fine but the `Twitter` login keeps **crashing** and no idea why? The crash leads to `AppDelegate.swift` saying there is a `Sigabrt error "thread 1 signal sigabrt"`

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Parse.setApplicationId("<MY ID>", clientKey:"<MY CLIENT KEY>")
    PFTwitterUtils.initializeWithConsumerKey("<CONSUMER KEY>", consumerSecret:"<CONSUMER SECRET>")
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions);
```

> NorthernLights[4119:358454] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
>   -[**NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d751e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010dadddeb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010d6548ce -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 318     3   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010d666c3b +[NSDictionary
>   dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 59    4   NorthernLights
>
>   0x000000010a77f349 -[PF_Twitter
>   _showWebViewDialogAsync:requestSecret:] + 265     5   NorthernLights                      0x000000010a78255a __38-[PF_Twitter
>   _performWebViewAuthAsync]_block_invoke_2 + 346    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e59be5d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12    7
>
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e5bc49b
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8  8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e5a42af _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738     9
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d6b1d09
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d6732c9 __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 2073    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d672828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488   12  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010f236ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161  13  UIKit
>   0x000000010bf52610 UIApplicationMain + 171    14  NorthernLights
>   0x000000010a5c90fd main + 109     15  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010e5f092d start + 1  16  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, when I implemented multiple url schemes in my app.
The reason for the crash was Spotify was handling the twitter url schemes in application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL)

I was able to resolve the issue by checking the type of url scheme coming.
For twitter I used

```
if url.scheme != nil && url.scheme!.hasPrefix("twitterkit"){ //Twitter SDK
        return TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
}  else{ //Other SDK's  }
```